# Program to display all logged in users via C program on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, unix

I have one program called `allloggedin.c`, whose purpose is to display all logged in users.

Whenever I try to run it on terminal (using gcc), it gives me error as 
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>
#include<utmp.h>

int main(void)
{
 struct utmp *n;
 char *a;
 int i;
 setutent();
 n=getutent();

 while(n!=NULL)
 {
  if(n->ut_type==7)
  {
   printf("%9s",n->ut_user);
   printf("%12s",n->ut_line);

   printf(" ");
   for(i=4;i<16;i++)
   printf("%c",a[i]);
   printf(" (");
   printf("%s10",n->ut_host);
   printf(")");
   printf("\n");
  }
  n=getutent();
 }
}
```

Can anybody please explain me this program?

Comment: You have not initialized `a`, but you accessing it: `printf("%c",a[i]);`. Btw, learn how to use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Comment: Isn't this what `who` is for?

Comment: I don't see any shell programming happening here

Comment: Next time, read [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking such a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Segmentation Fault you are getting is because of the line:

```
printf("%c",a[i]);
```

Since you didn't initialize the pointer `a`, it can point to any address, which may cause a Segmentation Fault when you dereference it.

I'm not sure what you are trying to print in the for loop so I removed it entirely from the code.

This is a cleaned version of the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>
#include<utmp.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct utmp *n;
  setutent();
  n=getutent();

  while(n) {
    if(n->ut_type==USER_PROCESS) {
      printf("%9s%12s (%s)\n", n->ut_user, n->ut_line, n->ut_host);
    }
    n=getutent();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I replaced the number 7 by the proper macro `USER_PROCESS`. Also, you can place all the prints in a single `printf` call.

So what the program basically does is to get the utmp struct for each user and print it in a fancy way.

For more information about the functions used and the utmp struct you can take a look at the [utmp.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html) reference.